# strftime in dates?

Tags: php, date

When I had UNIX timestamps, I'd write:

```
strftime("%A", $date)
```

But now I have datestamps, like "2011-08-02"

How can I make it output the weekday name, e.g "Sunday"?

Answer (score 2):

You can convert the date stamp to a timestamp using the function [`strtotime`](http://www.php.net/strtotime).
Once you have the timestamp, you can just use the function [`date`](http://www.php.net/date) to show the date in the desired format.

Comment: For example:

date("g:i a  F j Y", strtotime(time()));
//Will print 10:20 AM 20 july 2011

Comment: `date` vs `strftime` is not relevant to the question.

Answer (score 1):

First use the [strtotime](http://www.php.net/strtotime) function to convert the '2011-08-02' to a UNIX timestamp, and then proceed as you usually would

For example, the following are equivalent:

```
$date = 1312243200; // A unix timestamp
$date = strtotime('2011-08-02'); // The date that it represents
```

You can then do whatever you would usually do with the result

The strtotime() function is fairly forgiving in what date formats it accepts and even accepts values such as '8pm tomorrow' or 'last Monday' - See http://www.php.net/strtotime

Comment: Better `$date = strtotime('2011-08-02')` for symmetry

Comment: Agreed. Also made the answer more general.

Answer (score 0):

Use `date('l');` Add more properties like so: `date('l d-m-Y');`.

More info [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php)

Answer (score 0):

<sub>(2nd August 2011 was a Tuesday, not a Sunday.)</sub>

---

```
<?php
echo strftime("%A", strtotime("2011-08-02"));
// Output: "Tuesday"
?>
```

- [Live demo](http://codepad.org/88sYcfSp)
- [`strtotime` documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php)

Answer (score 0):

```
date('l',strtotime('2011-08-02'));
```